# Proof that the vector space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$ is infinite-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to use the following lemma:

> A vector space V is infinite-dimensional if and only if there exists a sequence of vectors $v_1,v_2,...$ such that $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ is linearly independent for every $n\in N$

Take a sequence of polynomials $p_i, i=0,1,...$  such that $deg(p_i)=i$. Now, given any $n\in N$, the subsequence $p_0,...,p_n$ is linearly indepedent, because if $a_0p_0+a_1p_1+...+a_np_n=0$ there is a $a_nz^n$ on the left side and not on the right side, therefore $a_n=0$ and so on for every other coefficient. Because polynomials are continuous functions, this implies that the vector space $V$ of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$ is infinite-dimensional.

Is this proof valid? I think this should work if I simply take $p_i=z^i$, does it work for the more general $deg(p_i)=i$ case?

Comment: It works for the genaral case also.

Comment: Alright, thanks!